# How to calculate combinations in Python

Tags: python

I want to calculate a combination set as a collection of all possible subsets of `k` items selected from `n` items. For example, if `n = 4` and `k = 3`, then the items are the integers `(0, 1, 2, 3)`, then there are `4` possible combination elements:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Is there a function to do it in Python?

Comment: @GinoMempin No, because I want fixed number of items `k` in this case, but thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itertools.combinations` produces the desired output:

```py
from itertools import combinations

n = 4
k = 3

# combinations() outputs tuples.
# Use list() to transform the tuples into lists.
print([list(combination) for combination in combinations(range(n), 3)])
```